# IXSomething vs ISomething

Tags: c++, windows, com

I stumbled upon a documentation where COM objects have two kinds of interfaces, one starting with `I`, second with `IX`. Documentation says that `IX` is derived from `IUnknown`, and `I` is derived from `IDispatch`.

Is it better to use `IX` interfaces if I use C++? As far as I understand the `I` interfaces are designed for scripting languages in this case? Are there any other differences?

Comment: I've been doing COM for a long time and this is the first I've heard of it.  This is certainly not standard or common, forget about IX.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684702%28VS.85%29.aspx IX seems to be C++ oriented.

Comment: I can think of a few reasons why they would do that (not necessarily good ones...:-) ). Maybe the class implementer: a) Didn't want to create a dual interface for some internal reason? b) Or didn't know they could? c) Used tools that didn't particularly help to implement them or support them? (can't think of any); d) Or they were stuck with a legacy interface that had not been defined as dual (e.g. created by someone who at the time was only concerned with ASP). At least (d) has a modicum of legitimacy.

Comment: The part with Quering IDispatch and requering real interface from it is annoying, but the rest of the COM stuff is really more naturas in the 'I' case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X belongs to the next word.  Feed vs XFeed.  "Extended", version 2 of the API.